# GLM - Are vectors and matrices guaranteed to be memory equivalent to their GLSL counterparts?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Intuitively I'd say yes, because otherwise this whole "following the GLSL specification" thing wouldn't really make that much sense. I didn't find this explicitly mentioned anywhere though. In code, I'm asking if

```
glm::someType something{...};
(float*)&something === glm::value_ptr(something)
```

(Of course not float* when using the double or half variants, but you get the point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "following the GLSL specification" thing wouldn't really make that much sense.

GLSL does not specify a memory layout. It merely defines the lexical structure of the various types, like which elements they have. GLM follows the same lexical structure, but it may follow whatever memory layout works best for it.

Note that the only interface between GLM and GLSL are glUniform and glVertexAttrib[Pointer] calls, and the memory layout of those is well known. And as long as GLM works with those, everything is fine.